# Including Logout functionality in _Layout ASP.NET 3.0 Razor Pages project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I have built a simple razor page application where login which uses AddAuthentication() and checks to ensure the username and password match the values in the db. Each page is then authorized based on that so only logged in users can move forward to other pages. My login view model includes the following type of authentication:

```
               var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, UserName)
                };
                var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

                if (RememberMe)
                {
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                        new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                        new AuthenticationProperties
                        {
                            IsPersistent = RememberMe,
                            ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(2)
                        });
                }
                else
                {
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                        new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));
                }
                return RedirectToPage("/index");
```

Now I need to create logout functionality. I feel as though logout in the navigation bar is pretty common. My navigation bar is built using shared _layout. So first I need to pass some sort of model to this _layout class so I can catch an onpost event to remove the session cookie or persistent cookie if it exists and redirect the user to the login page.

How can this be done without controllers to maintain a MVVM approach?

Second, in regards to logging out. I want to use

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {

        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        return RedirectToPage("/index");

    }
```

In the model I pass to _layout. However, using HttpContext will only work with PageModel so just creating model class doesnt seem to work but instead i Need to createa a partial PageModel class to pass to _layout. THoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use a separate Razor Page with code-behind that performs the logout. You should give some feed-back to the user after logout instead of just redirecting user to index page. Hence, you can have a link to your logout-page from your layout since logout can be done on GET.

Comment: Thanks. Based on your logic I have added a logout page and model and in my _layout use POST using this <form asp-page-handler="Logout" method="post" asp-page="/Logout"> layout. In the logout page model I call public async Task<IActionResult> Logout() but it is never used. What am I missing from this? Also, why not use POST rather get a GET request?

Comment: If you're going with POST, method must be named `OnPostLogout` in your code-behind. I don't see any point using POST for this, there is no data to send.

Comment: Ahhh yea I just realized that too. Still learning if you couldnt tell. I think you are right that POST is probably not worth it. When using GET do you just use the default OnGet method generated with new page models but with return type Task<IActionResult> (ie public Task<IActionResult> OnGetLogout())?

Comment: Yes, OnGet will suffice. With that you can skip redirect-after-post too :-)

Comment: Oddly enough doing custom asp-page-handler and calling Logout and creating method as OnGetLogout does not seem to do anything. Removing the handler and just doing OnGet works. I wonder why you cannot do that for OnGet. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Nice :-) Then you're a step further to be a developer. Please don't forget to accept my answer in order to close the case. BR

Comment: I hit the green check mark to accept but I guess I do not have the reputation yet to upvote it as well. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. When POSTing to other pages, use `<form method="post" asp-page="/Login">` and in code-behind, use OnPost